# What would cause memcached to return the wrong results?

Tags: django, memcached

I have a site running on an EC2 image I have bee updating for over a year. This week I have been busy building a new image, to move to 64bit instances. I've got everything installed, the code running, and I'm testing the site under the new setup. I start getting lots of weird problems and eventually realize it only happens when memcached is running.

essentially, memcache is sending the wrong entries back. It works if I use other django-supported caches, such as locmem:// or file:// but it fails on memcache. Most of it seems to work, but a few specific places, even in the template cache tags, it will return not just the wrong values, but entirely different types.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem in the way memcached was installed. I presume 64-bit memcached needs to be installed a different way than 32-bit.

The [memcached Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/memcached) might be a better place to ask.